# How to read file with different columns into vector then into class in c++?

Tags: c++

I have file that contains

```
Name    Age     FavSport
"Michael", 18, Soccer, Cricket, Hockey
"John", 18, Cricket
"Mitchell", 19, Soccer, Hockey
```

(There are alot more lines of data in file)
I have created a class

```
class team
{
std::string name;
int age;
vector<std::string> favSport;

team(std::string name, int age, vector<std::string> favSport)

std::string getname() const { return name; }
int getage() const { return age; }
const vector<std::string>& getfavSport() const { return favSport; }
~team();
}
```

Here is my code to read lines of file

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> teamVec;
    std::ifstream myfile("team.txt");
        if (!myfile) 
        {
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        while (std::getline(myfile, line))
        {
            teamVec.push_back(line);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to store the values of vector teamVec into team class. The favSport from file should store to vector of favSport in class (which is inside vector of team since student can have more then one fav sport)
Any help will be great thank you

Comment: Shouldn't you create an instance of that class first? By the way, why do you call the class `team` while the fields belong to a single player?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov thank you for reply, the code I did is long, that uploaded is just a small part of it hence few stuff are missing.

Comment: Then you need to clarify the question. Your question has no reasonable answers in current form.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It works for me.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Student {
    public:
    string name;
    int age;
    vector<string> favSport;
};

class Team {
    public:
    vector<Student> teamVec;
};

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> teamVec;
    std::ifstream myfile("team.txt");
    if (!myfile)
    {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    bool firstLine = true;
    Team myTeam;
    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if(firstLine) {
            firstLine = false;
        } else {
            Student temp;
            int times = 0;
            size_t pos = 0;
            std::string token;
            while ((pos = line.find(", ")) != std::string::npos) {
                token = line.substr(0, pos);
                times++;
                if(times == 1) {
                    temp.name = token.substr(1,token.size()-2);
                } else if(times == 2) {
                    temp.age = stoi(token);
                } else {
                    temp.favSport.push_back(token);
                }
                std::cout << token << std::endl;
                line.erase(0, pos + 2);
            }
            temp.favSport.push_back(line);
            myTeam.teamVec.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    // USE myTeam
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much this is the only place i was having trouble with and last part to complete mini project. thank you